# Distance from a point to a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you find the distance from a point to the plane when the point and the basis for the plane are given?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html

Comment: What if only the basis is given? For example, say a plane passes through origin and is the span of (1,0,-1) and (1,1,1)?

Comment: Then you find the equation of the plane first.

Comment: @vadim123 If to find the equation of the plane, do I convert the parametric form of the plane to ax+by+cz+d=0 form? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a plane given by the basis

$$\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\}$$

To find the distance from point $P$ to this plane, first find a vector orthogonal to this plane, so that that vector and this plane form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$$\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\1\end{pmatrix}\}$$

Find the representation of $P$ in this basis.

$$P = \frac{P_x-P_z}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}+\frac{P_x+P_y+P_z}{3}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\left(\frac{P_x+P_z}{2}-\frac{P_x+P_y+P_z}{3}\right)\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that the first two terms of this representation is the orthographic projection of $P$ onto the plane, and the third term is rejection. This means that the distance from the point to the plane is the magnitude of this vector.

$$\begin{Vmatrix}\left(\frac{P_x+P_z}{2}-\frac{P_x+P_y+P_z}{3}\right)\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\1\end{pmatrix}\end{Vmatrix}$$